# Docusign API Date and name tabs don't show

Tags: docusignapi

I can successfully create and manage envelopes/documents via the DocuSign API. However, while the SignHere tab works perfectly, the other tabs (fullName, date) won't show. As the 'anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent' flag is set to false, I should get an error message if the anchors were not found, which I don't. The pdf-file looks quite right. The anchors are NOT placed in any form fields. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot, Mario

---

### JSON:

```
{
    "recipients":   {
        "signers":  [{
                "email":    "info@xyz.com",
                "name": "Hans Wurst",
                "recipientId":  "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                            "anchorString": "*#dssng#*",
                            "anchorXOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorYOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                            "anchorUnits":  "pixels"
                        }],
                    "fullName": [{
                            "anchorString": "*#dsname#*",
                            "anchorXOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorYOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                            "anchorUnits":  "pixels"
                        }],
                    "date": [{
                            "anchorString": "*#dsdate#*",
                            "anchorXOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorYOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                            "anchorUnits":  "pixels"
                        }]
                }
            }]
    },
    "emailSubject": "Neues DocuSign-Dokument zum Unterzeichnen",
    "documents":    [{
            "documentId":   "1",
            "name": "Contract.pdf",
            "documentBase64":   "JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9n..."
        }],
    "status":   "sent"
}
```

Comment: are you sure the anchor string is present on the document?

Comment: can you try to change the anchor string of the date to the one of the SignHere, just to see what happens?

Comment: Hello Inbar, thanks for trying to help. I have switched the anchors of name tab and signature tab:

"signHereTabs": [{
                            "anchorString": "*#dsname#*",
                       ...
                        }],
"fullName": [{
                            "anchorString": "*#dsname#*",
                     ...
                        }],

Result: The name tab still doesn't appear, the signature tab shows where the name tab is supposed to show. Everything but the signature tab seems to be ignored.

Comment: found your issue in the JSON. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your JSON is the the other tab groups should be named in plural like this:

```
"tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                            "anchorString": "*#dssng#*",
                            "anchorXOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorYOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                            "anchorUnits":  "pixels"
                        }],
                    "fullNameTabs": [{
                            "anchorString": "*#dsname#*",
                            "anchorXOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorYOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                            "anchorUnits":  "pixels"
                        }],
                    "dateTabs": [{
                            "anchorString": "*#dsdate#*",
                            "anchorXOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorYOffset":    "0",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                            "anchorUnits":  "pixels"
                        }]
```

Comment: Inbar, you made my day! I just couldn't see it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anytime, Happy to Help!